# Access structure members with a pointer

Tags: c, iterator, structure

In C, I am having a structure like this

```
typedef struct
{
 char *msg1;
 char *msg2;
 .
 .
 char *msgN;
}some_struct;

some_struct struct1;
some_struct *pstruct1 = &struct1;
```

I want to keep a pointer or a varible which when incremented or decremented, gives the next/last member variable of this structure. I do not want to use array of char * since it is already designed like this.

I tried using the union and structure combination, but I don't know how to write code for that.

Thought iterator may help but this is C. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: all members are going to be char* ???

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, safely. You can take a chance that the adjacent character pointers are really adjacent (with no padding) as if they were in an array, but you can't be sure so that's pretty much straight into the undefined behavior minefield.

You can abstract it to an index, and do something like:

```
char * get_pointer(some_struct *p, int index)
{
  if(index == 0)
    return p->msg1;
  if(index == 1)
    return p->msg2;
  /* and so on */
  return NULL;
}
```

Then you get to work with an index which you can increment/decrement freely, and just call `get_pointer()` to map it to a message pointer when needed.

Comment: I can't quote chapter and verse, but AFAIK if the structure consists only of members of the same type, the compiler is not allowed to pad them. Calculating the *last* member, as shown in my answer, might be dodgy ground, but I believe even that is correct if the structure is homogenous, as shown in the OP's example.

Comment: +1. C99 6.7.2.1-p12,13: **12** Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an *implementation-defined* manner appropriate to its type. **13** Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Comment: This is not the reason you cannot do that safely. You can test the size of the struct at compile-time and cause an error if there is any padding. So the program will compile only if the structure has no padding. The reason you cannot do that safely, with simple pointer increments, is that the standard does not guarantee that pointer arithmetic works other than in arrays, and a struct is not an array. However, there is a way around that.

Comment: +1 This solution is quite reasonable, understandable, and safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using strict C, but you need to take certain precautions to ensure compliance with the standard. I will explain these below, but the precautions you need to take are:

(0) Ensure there is no padding by including this declaration:

```
extern int CompileTimeAssert[
    sizeof(some_struct) == NumberOfMembers * sizeof(char *) ? 1 : -1];
```

(1) Initialize the pointer from the address of the structure, not the address of a member:

```
char **p = (char **) (char *) &struct1;
```

(I suspect the above is not necessary, but I would have to insert more reasoning from the C standard.)

(2) Increment the pointer in the following way, instead of using `++` or adding one:

```
p = (char **) ((char *) p + sizeof(char *));
```

Here are explanations.

The declaration in (0) acts as a compile-time assertion. If there is no padding in the struct, then the size of the struct equals the number of members multiplied by the size of a member. Then the ternary operator evaluates to 1, the declaration is valid, and the compiler proceeds. If there is padding, the sizes are not equal, the ternary operator evaluates to -1, and the declaration is invalid because an array cannot have a negative size. Then the compiler reports an error and terminates.

Thus, a program containing this declaration will compile only if the struct does not have padding. Additionally, the declaration will not consume any space (it only declares an array that is never defined), and it may be repeated with other expressions (that evaluate to an array size of 1 if their condition is true), so different assertions may be tested with the same array name.

Items (1) and (2) deal with the problem that pointer arithmetic is normally guaranteed to work only within arrays (including a notional sentinel element at the end) (per C 2011 6.5.6 8). However, the C standard makes special guarantees for character types, in C 2011 6.3.2.3 7. A pointer to the struct may be converted to a pointer to a character type, and it will yield a pointer to the lowest addressed byte of the struct. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

In (1), we know from C 2011 6.3.2.3 7, that `(char *) &struct1` is a pointer to the first byte of `struct1`. When converted to `(char **)`, it must be a pointer to the first member of `struct1` (in particular thanks to C 2011 6.5.9 6, which guarantees that equal pointers point to the same object, even if they have different types).

Finally, (2) works around the fact that array arithmetic is not directly guaranteed to work on our pointer. That is, `p++` would be incrementing a pointer that is not strictly in an array, so the arithmetic is not guaranteed by 6.5.6 8. So we convert it to a `char *`, for which increments are guaranteed to work by 6.3.2.3 7, we increment it four times, and we convert it back to `char **`. This must yield a pointer to the next member, since there is no padding.

One might claim that adding the size of `char **` (say 4) is not the same as four increments of one `char`, but certainly the intent of the standard is to allow one to address the bytes of an object in a reasonable way. However, if you want to avoid even this criticism, you can change `+ sizeof(char *)` to be `+1+1+1+1` (on implementations where the size is 4) or `+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1` (where it is 8).

Comment: +1 for the _0:compile-time assertion_ The others are much too clever for my taste :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the address of the first member and store it to `char **`:

```
char **first = &struct1.msg1;
char **last = &struct1.msg1 + sizeof(some_struct) / sizeof(char *) - 1;

char **ptr = first;  /* *ptr is struct.msg1 */
++ptr;               /* now *ptr is struct1.msg2 */
```

This assumes that the structure only contains `char *` members.

Comment: There's pointer arithmetic problems in the `last` computation; the `+` will be in units of `some_struct`. Also not sure about the `&struct.msg1`, I guess `some_` is missing there.

Comment: It was supposed to be `&struct1.msg1` (fixed in the edit), i.e. the address of the concrete member. Since the member is a `char *`, the `+` will be in `char *` units, which is required.